# Getting jQuery to make a new line inside a DIV when returning from an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <script>   
     $.ajax
         ({
             url: "../getStatus/",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(json) 
             {            
                $('#ajaxLog').html(json.status+"<br/>");
             }
         });

</script>

 //Need this section to make a new line when refreshed
<div id = ajaxLog style="width:50%"></div>
```

This needs to be an accumulative, returned message to the webpage. Each time the process starts/stop/suspends it will be displayed. The displayed message will not keep saying stopped/started/ etc. when remaining in a state - rather displayed each time these states change then it wont be redisplayed constantly -- NOT like jquery.append() does.

**Desired**

```
started 10:48
stoped 10:50
Started 12:53
suspended 3:34
Started 3:40
```

**NOT DESIRED**

```
started 10:48
started 10:48
started 10:48
started 10:48
started 10:48
started 10:48
started 10:48
stoped 10:50
.
.
```

> and so on

(like append() would do)

Comment: I notice you've added `</br>` to your HTML. If this is what you are reporting not working then replace it with `<br />`

Comment: And what do you mean by 'accumulative return message'? Sorry, this doesn't make sense. Can you include some exampels of what you expect to soo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    <script>   
    //Use this
    last=null;
     $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "../getStatus/",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) 
                {
                        //Replace this line
                        //$('#ajaxLog').html(json.status+"<br/>");

                        //with this:
                        if(last!=json.status)
                        {
                            $('#ajaxLog').append(json.status+"<br/>");
                            //or: $('#ajaxLog').append('<p>'+json.status+'</p>');
                            last=json.status;
                        }
                 }
             });

</script>

 //Need this section to make a new line when refreshed
<div id = ajaxLog style="width:50%"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as *new line* in HTML. You could use a `<br/>` tag to achieve a *new line* semantics:

```
$('#ajaxLog').append(json.status + '<br/>');
```

Or put the contents into a div:

```
$('#ajaxLog').append('<div>' + json.status + '</div>');
```

Also you should use the `.append()` method instead of `.html()` to avoid overwriting the contents of the `ajaxLog` div each time this is invoked.

Comment: @Mrshll187, you should use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line break in the HTML?

```
success: function(json) 
{
    $('#ajaxLog').html("<br />" + json.status+);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misreading this, you are calling the html() method which will replace the full contents of the div.  Are you really trying to append the results (on a new line) to whatever is already inside the div?

My apologies if I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ajax settings have an additional

`data: ''`

so it looks like

`url: '../getStatus/', data: '', dataType: 'json', success: ...`

? I'm pretty much sure I've read this somewhere.